# pre_word() Function in Python

Tags: python

I wrote the code below that has a single string parameter that checks if a single word is starting with "pre".

It needs to check if word starts with "pre" and if word .isalpha(). if all checks pass: `return` **True**. if any checks fail: return **False**. **Test:** get input using the directions: `*enter a word that starts with` `"pre"*`:. call `pre_word()` with the input string. test **if** return value is **False** and print message explaining not a `"pre"` word. **else** print message explaining is a valid `"pre"` word

**However, my code (second if/else part) doesn't work. It ends after return False:**

```
word = input("enter a word that starts with \"pre\": ")

def pre_word(word):
    if word.startswith("pre") and word.isalpha():
        return True
    else:
        return False

        if word == False:
            print('this is not a \"pre\" word')

        else:
            print('this is a valid \"pre\" word')

pre_word("publication")
```

Output:

```
enter a word that starts with "pre": publication
False
```

What do I need to change in my code to get my second part also be working?

PS. I learn python by myself. It is not a homework exercise.

Comment: What are you checking here?`if word == False:`? It checks if a word is empty or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement in 1st else ends the else loop. You can do

```py
def pre_word(word):
    if word.startswith("pre") and word.isalpha():
        print('this is a valid \"pre\" word')
        return True
    else:
        print('this is not a \"pre\" word')
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Python will exit a function when it reaches a return statement, so move the return False to the bottom, after the if/else construct.

EDIT: @dumbPy's answer is better because simply moving the return False will not entirely solve your problem. Only the "else" in the nested if/else will execute if that's all you do..

Answer (score 1):

```
def pre_word(word):
    if word.startswith("pre") and word.isalpha():
        return True
    else:
        return False

word = input("enter a word that starts with \"pre\": ")

word = pre_word(word)

if word == False:
    print('this is not a \"pre\" word')

else:
    print('this is a valid \"pre\" word')
```

[image: Output 1]
[image: Output 2]

Answer (score 1):

As you are using return statement in your function's top `if-else` statement so before coming to inner `else's` `if-else` condition you are returning from the function so inner `if-else` become unreachable.

To avoid this see below answer by @dumbPy